# my script is working on jfiddle only but not on local machine

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have a codes on Jsfiddle but not showing on realtime project i have consider external resources. Jfiddle has a tab menu and each tab is showing different chart on it like bar chart or pie chart or line chart.

I put both the css and js files on same page and also on the different page than also its not showing the js function on other tab.

Please let me know the solution i am trying from very long but its not working.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxshR/)

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
    <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
        <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
            <div id="jQueryVisualizeChart1"></div>
            <br />
            <table id="table1">
                <caption>2010 Employee Sales by Department</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <th scope="col">food</th>
                        <th scope="col">auto</th>
                        <th scope="col">household</th>
                        <th scope="col">furniture</th>
                        <th scope="col">kitchen</th>
                        <th scope="col">bath</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Mary</th>
                        <td>190</td>
                        <td>160</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>120</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>70</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Tom</th>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>45</td>
                        <td>35</td>
                        <td>49</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
            <div id="jQueryVisualizeChart2"></div>
            <br />
            <table id="table2">
                <caption>2010 Employee Sales by Department</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <th scope="col">food</th>
                        <th scope="col">auto</th>
                        <th scope="col">household</th>
                        <th scope="col">furniture</th>
                        <th scope="col">kitchen</th>
                        <th scope="col">bath</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Mary</th>
                        <td>190</td>
                        <td>160</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>120</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>70</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Tom</th>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>45</td>
                        <td>35</td>
                        <td>49</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
(function () { // BeginSpryComponent

    if (typeof Spry == "undefined") window.Spry = {};
    if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels = function (element, opts) {
        this.element = this.getElement(element);
        this.defaultTab = 0; // Show the first panel by default.
        this.tabSelectedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
        this.tabHoverClass = "TabbedPanelsTabHover";
        this.tabFocusedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabFocused";
        this.panelVisibleClass = "TabbedPanelsContentVisible";
        this.focusElement = null;
        this.hasFocus = false;
        this.currentTabIndex = 0;
        this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
        this.nextPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT;
        this.previousPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT;

        Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions(this, opts);

        if (typeof (this.defaultTab) == "number") {
            if (this.defaultTab < 0) this.defaultTab = 0;
            else {
                var count = this.getTabbedPanelCount();
                if (this.defaultTab >= count) this.defaultTab = (count > 1) ? (count - 1) : 0;
            }

            this.defaultTab = this.getTabs()[this.defaultTab];
        }

        if (this.defaultTab) this.defaultTab = this.getElement(this.defaultTab);

        this.attachBehaviors();
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElement = function (ele) {
        if (ele && typeof ele == "string") return document.getElementById(ele);
        return ele;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElementChildren = function (element) {
        var children = [];
        var child = element.firstChild;
        while (child) {
            if (child.nodeType == 1 /* Node.ELEMENT_NODE */ ) children.push(child);
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return children;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.addClassName = function (ele, className) {
        if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) != -1)) return;
        ele.className += (ele.className ? " " : "") + className;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.removeClassName = function (ele, className) {
        if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1)) return;
        ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + className + "\\b", "g"), "");
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions = function (obj, optionsObj, ignoreUndefinedProps) {
        if (!optionsObj) return;
        for (var optionName in optionsObj) {
            if (ignoreUndefinedProps && optionsObj[optionName] == undefined) continue;
            obj[optionName] = optionsObj[optionName];
        }
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabGroup = function () {
        if (this.element) {
            var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
            if (children.length) return children[0];
        }
        return null;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabs = function () {
        var tabs = [];
        var tg = this.getTabGroup();
        if (tg) tabs = this.getElementChildren(tg);
        return tabs;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanelGroup = function () {
        if (this.element) {
            var children = this.getElementChildren(this.element);
            if (children.length > 1) return children[1];
        }
        return null;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getContentPanels = function () {
        var panels = [];
        var pg = this.getContentPanelGroup();
        if (pg) panels = this.getElementChildren(pg);
        return panels;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getIndex = function (ele, arr) {
        ele = this.getElement(ele);
        if (ele && arr && arr.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (ele == arr[i]) return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabIndex = function (ele) {
        var i = this.getIndex(ele, this.getTabs());
        if (i < 0) i = this.getIndex(ele, this.getContentPanels());
        return i;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getCurrentTabIndex = function () {
        return this.currentTabIndex;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getTabbedPanelCount = function (ele) {
        return Math.min(this.getTabs().length, this.getContentPanels().length);
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener = function (element, eventType, handler, capture) {
        try {
            if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
            else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
        } catch (e) {}
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.cancelEvent = function (e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        else e.cancelBubble = true;

        return false;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabClick = function (e, tab) {
        this.showPanel(tab);
        return this.cancelEvent(e);
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabMouseOver = function (e, tab) {
        this.addClassName(tab, this.tabHoverClass);
        return false;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabMouseOut = function (e, tab) {
        this.removeClassName(tab, this.tabHoverClass);
        return false;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabFocus = function (e, tab) {
        this.hasFocus = true;
        this.addClassName(tab, this.tabFocusedClass);
        return false;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabBlur = function (e, tab) {
        this.hasFocus = false;
        this.removeClassName(tab, this.tabFocusedClass);
        return false;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_UP = 38;
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_DOWN = 40;
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT = 37;
    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT = 39;



    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.onTabKeyDown = function (e, tab) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!this.hasFocus || (key != this.previousPanelKeyCode && key != this.nextPanelKeyCode)) return true;

        var tabs = this.getTabs();
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        if (tabs[i] == tab) {
            var el = false;
            if (key == this.previousPanelKeyCode && i > 0) el = tabs[i - 1];
            else if (key == this.nextPanelKeyCode && i < tabs.length - 1) el = tabs[i + 1];

            if (el) {
                this.showPanel(el);
                el.focus();
                break;
            }
        }

        return this.cancelEvent(e);
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.preorderTraversal = function (root, func) {
        var stopTraversal = false;
        if (root) {
            stopTraversal = func(root);
            if (root.hasChildNodes()) {
                var child = root.firstChild;
                while (!stopTraversal && child) {
                    stopTraversal = this.preorderTraversal(child, func);
                    try {
                        child = child.nextSibling;
                    } catch (e) {
                        child = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return stopTraversal;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.addPanelEventListeners = function (tab, panel) {
        var self = this;
        Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "click", function (e) {
            return self.onTabClick(e, tab);
        }, false);
        Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseover", function (e) {
            return self.onTabMouseOver(e, tab);
        }, false);
        Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(tab, "mouseout", function (e) {
            return self.onTabMouseOut(e, tab);
        }, false);

        if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation) {

            var tabIndexEle = null;
            var tabAnchorEle = null;

            this.preorderTraversal(tab, function (node) {
                if (node.nodeType == 1 /* NODE.ELEMENT_NODE */ ) {
                    var tabIndexAttr = tab.attributes.getNamedItem("tabindex");
                    if (tabIndexAttr) {
                        tabIndexEle = node;
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (!tabAnchorEle && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a") tabAnchorEle = node;
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (tabIndexEle) this.focusElement = tabIndexEle;
            else if (tabAnchorEle) this.focusElement = tabAnchorEle;

            if (this.focusElement) {
                Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "focus", function (e) {
                    return self.onTabFocus(e, tab);
                }, false);
                Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "blur", function (e) {
                    return self.onTabBlur(e, tab);
                }, false);
                Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "keydown", function (e) {
                    return self.onTabKeyDown(e, tab);
                }, false);
            }
        }
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.showPanel = function (elementOrIndex) {
        var tpIndex = -1;

        if (typeof elementOrIndex == "number") tpIndex = elementOrIndex;
        else // Must be the element for the tab or content panel.
        tpIndex = this.getTabIndex(elementOrIndex);

        if (!tpIndex < 0 || tpIndex >= this.getTabbedPanelCount()) return;

        var tabs = this.getTabs();
        var panels = this.getContentPanels();

        var numTabbedPanels = Math.max(tabs.length, panels.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < numTabbedPanels; i++) {
            if (i != tpIndex) {
                if (tabs[i]) this.removeClassName(tabs[i], this.tabSelectedClass);
                if (panels[i]) {
                    this.removeClassName(panels[i], this.panelVisibleClass);
                    panels[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        this.addClassName(tabs[tpIndex], this.tabSelectedClass);
        this.addClassName(panels[tpIndex], this.panelVisibleClass);
        panels[tpIndex].style.display = "block";

        this.currentTabIndex = tpIndex;
    };

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.attachBehaviors = function (element) {
        var tabs = this.getTabs();
        var panels = this.getContentPanels();
        var panelCount = this.getTabbedPanelCount();

        for (var i = 0; i < panelCount; i++)
        this.addPanelEventListeners(tabs[i], panels[i]);

        this.showPanel(this.defaultTab);
    };

})();

$(function () {
    $('#table1').visualize({
        type: 'bar',
        height: '260px',
        width: '420px',
        appendTitle: true,
        lineWeight: 4,
        colors: ['#be1e2d', '#666699', '#92d5ea', '#ee8310', '#8d10ee', '#5a3b16', '#26a4ed', '#f45a90', '#e9e744']
    }).appendTo('#jQueryVisualizeChart').trigger('visualizeRefresh1');

});
$(function () {
    $('#table2').visualize({
        type: 'line',
        height: '300px',
        width: '420px',
        appendTitle: true,
        lineWeight: 4,
        colors: ['#be1e2d', '#666699', '#92d5ea', '#ee8310', '#8d10ee', '#5a3b16', '#26a4ed', '#f45a90', '#e9e744']
    }).appendTo('#jQueryVisualizeChart').trigger('visualizeRefresh2');

});

var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
```

```css
.dwpeAd {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #F4F3Ea;
    position:fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.visualize {
    margin: 20px 0 0 30px;
}
.TabbedPanels {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.TabbedPanelsTabGroup {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.TabbedPanelsTab {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    font: bold 0.7em sans-serif;
    background-color: #DDD;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
    border-top: solid 1px #999;
    border-right: solid 1px #999;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.TabbedPanelsTabHover {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.TabbedPanelsTabSelected {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
.TabbedPanelsTab a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.TabbedPanelsContentGroup {
    clear: both;
    border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-top: solid 1px #999;
    border-right: solid 1px #999;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.TabbedPanelsContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 4px;
}
.TabbedPanelsContentVisible {
}
.VTabbedPanels {
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
}
.VTabbedPanels .TabbedPanelsTabGroup {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    height: 20em;
    background-color: #EEE;
    position: relative;
    border-top: solid 1px #999;
    border-right: solid 1px #999;
    border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
}
.VTabbedPanels .TabbedPanelsTab {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
.VTabbedPanels .TabbedPanelsTabSelected {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}
.VTabbedPanels .TabbedPanelsContentGroup {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 30em;
    height: 20em;
}
/* Styles for Printing */
 @media print {
    .TabbedPanels {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
    .TabbedPanelsContentGroup {
        display: block !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .TabbedPanelsContent {
        overflow: visible !important;
        display: block !important;
        clear:both !important;
    }
    .TabbedPanelsTab {
        overflow: visible !important;
        display: block !important;
        clear:both !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain a bit more, what is your question

Comment: I dont know why people are down voting this. I copy all the css, js and html files of the jsfiddle to my project but its not showing the same output as the jsfiddle. I want the same tab menu to appear on my project also but its not the same. When I click the second tab in jsfiddle its shwoing the chart but on  my real project when I click the second tab its not showing the chart. I am confuse why its like this. Could you please let me know.

Comment: That's wired, because I've tried edit the JSfiddle code but it seems like system denied my request.

Comment: @yotam, could you please let me know what we can do than ? I am working this from three days then also I cant able to achive this.

Comment: @user2841252 What doesn't it showing you? I can see changes when I'm moving tab to tab.. Such as table changes.

Comment: @yotam, can you make it to get different chart when you click the both tabs. For me, its showing the chart only on the first tab but when I click the other chart its not showing. Jsfiddle is shwoing different chart or graph when click other tab but when I copy the codes to html files its not the same. Do you get the different chart ??

Comment: can you please come to skype or other messenger to discuss this please...

Comment: @user2841252 You right, I don't. Do you mind creating new specific fiddle without the table scripts, that having me confusing. (I need only the tab scripts)

Comment: @Yotam, chart will not display if there is no table script. But the hint is both charts display correctly if there is no tab menu. If the tables on the one page then there is no such problem. But I want it to come on a tab menu.

Comment: @yotam, please let me know if I can provide some more information.

Comment: @user2841252 I think you should use JavaScript to switch tabs. You're using wrong way which causing this error. (Using JS will able you to choose what content will be appear in your tab)

Comment: @yotam, I used js tab also, I used js switch statement also but the result is same. I am doing this from 3 days... I dont know wheres the problem. Even this is thrid time I am asking in stackoverflow but no response.

Comment: @user2841252 Start answering questions and get raputition then you can start a bounty. I'm sorry but I can't find the answer.

Comment: @yotam, Hmm, ok bro for your suggestion. can we have skype conversation ??

Comment: Thanks you I sent u the request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Every tab different js function on Tab Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185089/every-tab-different-js-function-on-tab-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not copy the 'external resources' on left menu.